# Android Adding IF statement

Tags: android, integer, spinner, linear-algebra

In my application I'm trying to work out the cost of staying a hotel for multiple nights. Currently I'm calculating the cost of staying at the hotel at a flat rate but I want the user to receive a discount for staying for longer than three days. For example at the moment my application charges the user £45 per night at the hotel but I want it to charge £35 for any additional nights over three nights

Current example of my code

Variables

```
  Int standardRate = 45;
  Int additionalNights = 35;
  Spinner nightSpinner;
```

Contents of my current if statement

```
int answer = standardRate * nightSpinner

txtCost.setText(Integer.toString(answer));
```

Apologies for how little code I have as I don't currently have my application in front of me.

Comment: where is the no. of days? the logic is pretty straightforward, you should try it yourself

Comment: So what's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it help you................

```
int answer,spinnerValue=Integer.parseInt(nightSpinner..getSelectedItem());
if(spinnerValue<=3){
 answer = standardRate * spinnerValue;}
else{
 answer =(standardRate * 3) + (additionalNights * spinnerValue-3);}
          //for 3 days      and    extra days charges
```

enjoy coding...................

Answer (score 0):

Take the value from Spinner and write like that

```
if(nightspinner.get(position) > 3) {
ans = nightspinner.get(position)*aditionalnights;
else
ans = nightspinner.get(position)*standardnights;
```